# Puppeteer UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

After changing to my laptop from my desktop, every time I try to run a puppeteer program the follow error occurs:

```
(node:69) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Timed out after 30000 ms while trying to connect to the browser! Only Chrome at revision r901912 is guaranteed to work.
    at Timeout.onTimeout (/mnt/c/Users/trgre/OneDrive/Desktop/puppeteer-Core/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:208:20)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(node:69) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:69) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a 
non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help must 
include the desired behavior and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful 
to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In addition to code, what OS/environment settings are present on each of your different devices? We have no idea what variables might account for the problem so please try to provide the background info necessary to diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

*Most likely cause* is the Puppeteer driver not matching your Chromeium version.

From the docs:

> Note: When you install Puppeteer, it downloads a recent version of
> Chromium (~170MB Mac, ~282MB Linux, ~280MB Win) that is guaranteed to
> work with the API. To skip the download, download into another path,
> or download a different browser, see [Environment
> variables](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v10.4.0/docs/api.md#environment-variables).

There you'll find an environment variable: `PUPPETEER_CHROMIUM_REVISION`

Alternatively you could reinstall Puppeteer and allow it to install the correct version of Chromium.